# SQL Anywhere Syntax error near @

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures, sqlanywhere

I am working in ASA 11 with store procedures.
Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "DBA"."pa_select_employ"(
        @cod nVARCHAR(10),
        @name nvarchar(15) OUTPUT)
BEGIN
    SELECT @name=name_employ FROM EMPLOY //the line 6
    WHERE COD_EMPLOY=@cod
END
```

Send the variable @cod and need result @name OUTPUT

Can't Save but shows message:

> The procedure 'xxx' could not be modified in the database. Syntax
>   error near '@name' on line 6 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][SQL Anywhere]Syntax
>   error near '@name' on line 6 SQLCODE: -131 SQLSTATE: 42000

In the Interactive SQL the select is OK.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(15)
 SELECT @name=name_employ FROM EMPLOY
    WHERE COD_EMPLOY='333333'
```

please help me find the syntax error? (I speak Spanish.)

Comment: "HELP, I Speak spanish" - Sorry, I can't help you with that. ;)

Comment: @hcovenas On the line in which you get the syntax error, are you trying to select name_employ from EMPLOY and giving it the alias '@name'?

Comment: Yes, the name_employ is the column (table EMPLOY)
@name is var of RETURN

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the procedure definition to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "DBA"."pa_select_employ"(
    IN @cod nVARCHAR(10),
    OUT @name nvarchar(15))
BEGIN
    SELECT @name=name_employ FROM EMPLOY //the line 6
    WHERE COD_EMPLOY=@cod
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes how thw prodedure es ok, but in Powerbuilder show te error

`ERRORSQLSTATE = S1105

[Sybase][ODBC Driver]Invalid parameter type



DECLARE pa_find_name PROCEDURE FOR pa_select_employ  

         cod =:sle_cod.text,   //input
 
         name =: sle_name.text ;  //out

EXECUTE pa_find_name;`

IF SQLCA.sqlcode<>0 THEN
    MESSAGEBOX("","ERROR" + SQLCA.sqlerrtext )
END IF

Comment: Is COD_EMPLOY a numeric field? cause then the nvarchar data type would indeed be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, it was solved. Try changing the procedure definition

Comment: Could you please elobrate.